# How to create fixed input mask?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try create a fixed input mask with javascript library https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#phone-1").inputmask("+996 999 999999",{ "clearIncomplete": true });
});
```

I want to have `+996`  fixed and user can type other numbers only, how can I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the static elements which are equal to a definition.
See https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask#escape-special-mask-chars

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#phone-1").inputmask("+\\9\\96 999 999999",{ "clearIncomplete": true });
});
```